# Spring remote services with a transaction context

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, remoting, application-server

I have the following scenario:
I have an interface-server which listens on a queue and receives messages from the "outside world". This server then calls a "internal", business, service which in turn calls other services and so on.
These services can each reside on a different machine, and can be clustered for that matter.
I need the notion of a transaction to span across these services and machines.
My development stack includes Spring (3.0.5) and JPA 2.0(Hibernate in background) on a J2SE environment.
Can I acheive this without an app-server? Assuming I plug-in an external JTA transaction-manager (like atomikos for example)
We've chosen to go with Spring for many reasons the most important ones were the service abstractions, intensive DI and the ability to work without a heavy app-server. I know we can use spring in an app-server but if someone is to recommend this I'd like to hear why this should be done, assuming I can forefit spring and go all app-server.

BTW, just to reassure anyone reading this post: Yes, we've thought of the problematic issues of a distributed transaction but we still think we will need such a transaction as this is the business logic of the service and it will need to be across machine as some of the services will be under a lot of pressure.

Thanks in advance,
Ittai

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html

Comment: @Trever thanks for the link but as far as I can tell the article refers to distributed transactions across resources and not across machines so it is irrelevant for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using JBoss with Spring.
JBoss indeed supplied the distributed transactions that were needed while Spring contained all DI and such.
We still kept spring as we felt its IOC was cleaner and more comfortable.
It is possible we should have used CDI in jboss but that was not on our radar.

Comment: Hi, Ittai, can you describe your setup in more detail? Are you using REST services? Are all your services on the same machine (JBoss server)? Are you using JTA (UserTransaction) to begin/ commit/ rollback.

Answer (score 0):

We use Spring 3 and Atomikos for distributed transactions (xa) on apache tomcat and oracle databases in production, so this for us a very usefull setup. Have a look at the atomicos spring integration example:

http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about your setup? Do you use distributed transactions across machines? Or just across various resources in the same machine. The former solution is what I'm looking for and in the link I did not find any mention of it

Comment: Hi, we distribute transactions for different databases, not for different tomcats. We do not use JMS or AMQP for communication yet, but web servies and we do not rely on distributed transactions there.